# Out of stack space (Error 28) VBA

Tags: vba, fortran

I am trying to convert an old Fortran program with a lot of nested goto statements to VBA but I am getting error mentioned in the title. The way I am converting is each statement, I made it a function and instead of **goto** then i call the function or statement, but apparently that's not a proper way of doing it. What else can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide what you have done, most likely you have a loop that never ends.

Comment: You maybe calling the same function or sub infinitely

Comment: msdn says: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot see where the endless loop is, try adding a public counter to all of the functions. If it exceeds a given value, stop the program. Then try to debug with <kbd>F8</kbd> to see the endless loop. I mean something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public counter  As Long

Public Sub TestMe()

    While True
        FunctionSomething
    Wend

End Sub

Public Function FunctionSomething()

    counter = counter + 1
    If counter > 100 Then Stop

End Function
```

Now if you run `TestMe` it would stop on the 100th iteration.

Comment: 10000 is already pretty damn deep in the call stack... 10-20 should be enough!

Comment: ok, let's leave it as 100, @Mat'sMug.